# How can I get my looped function to automate through every row?

Tags: r

[image]

I am working with a dataset with 45 rows and 6 columns (I have removed 2 that are not relevant). I'm trying to create a function that will go through each row and calculate Simpson's diversity (using column values). The equation is: `D = Σni(ni-1)  /  N(N-1)`, where n is the value in each column, and N is the value of all columns in a row added together - hopefully it makes sense, the actual equation isnt really important to my question though.

I have code that loops through the rows and inside this loop is another loop to go through all the columns in a row and calculate abundance for them. My goal in the end of the loop is to put them together into vector 'simp' I created to hold all the answers (simpsons diversity for each row. This function is supposed to be generic so it can be used with any dataset.

As you can see in my code and the results, the vector is showing up with all the rows, but only the first row has the answer. Anyone know how to make this function more automated so it will run through every row and put the answers in my vector?
edit - it needs to be like this for my assignment, I can't use pre-existing simpson diversity functions:(

```
#My code: (killdat is the dataset I am working with, with the two columns removed).
#simp is my empty vector to hold answers
killdat=select(killarney, -Lake, -Status)

test=function(x){
  simp=vector(mode="logical", length=nrow(Df))
  for(j in 1:nrow(Df)){
    for(i in 1:ncol(Df)){
      abun=(Df[j,i])*(Df[j,i]-1)
      n=Df[j,]
    }
    N=sum(n)
    num=sum(abun)
    den=N*(N-1)
    simp[j]=1-(num/den);return(simp)
  }}

test(killdat)

#my output:
[1] 0.9396795 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[13] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[25] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[37] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you `debugonce(test)` then use `test(killdat)`, stepping through with `s` then `ls()`  to track your `i,j,n,N,simp` values you'll probably find `simp[j, ]` and friends want an `i`. This comment just about 'what happened to my nested loop`?

Comment: Hi @Chris thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean by stepping through with s and ls(), do you mean using it within my loops? Also  I tried using simp[j,i] but got an error because of an incorrect number of subscripts on matrix. Sorry I am relatively new to R!

Comment: `debugonce(test)` tells R,  next time you see `test(some_data)` go into debug mode. `s` step (return), you advance 1 step in func, `n` (return), advance more, `c` run to end of func or error. As you step through you can check values to see if they are what you expect for `i,j,N&etc` and `ls()` at steps where new variables come in or if you forget what variables you're tracking. So my comments are just how to debug a function. I'd accept@till answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating some data that resembles your description.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(abdiv)

killarney <-
  tibble(
    id = 1:45,
    var1 = sample(1:100, 45),
    var2 = sample(1:100, 45),
    var3 = sample(1:100, 45),
    var4 = sample(1:100, 45),
    var5 = sample(1:100, 45),
    var6 = sample(1:100, 45)
  )

killarney
#> # A tibble: 45 × 7
#>       id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1    30     6     8    92    30   100
#>  2     2    20    99     2    34    29    78
#>  3     3    24     3    37    96    26    69
#>  4     4    33    50     4   100    56    77
#>  5     5    73    59    70    70    64    55
#>  6     6    12    14    61    29    55    14
#>  7     7    70    97    81    82    93    80
#>  8     8    52     2    57    66    13    53
#>  9     9    57    81    86    94    16    98
#> 10    10    37    40    18    71    75    17
#> # ℹ 35 more rows
```

1. The `abdiv` package has a `simpson()` function **OR** you can
   implement your own custom function.
2. Instead of operationg on rows it is easier to `pivot_longer()` the data
   first and then operate on a grouped `data.frame`.

```r
# custom simpson function
simpson_func <- 
  function(x) {
    N <- sum(x)
    D = sum(x * (x - 1)) / (N * (N - 1))
    1 - D
}

killarney |>
  pivot_longer(-id) |>
  group_by(id) |>
  summarise(simp = simpson_func(value))
#> # A tibble: 45 × 2
#>       id  simp
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1 0.715
#>  2     2 0.736
#>  3     3 0.748
#>  4     4 0.781
#>  5     5 0.834
#>  6     6 0.767
#>  7     7 0.833
#>  8     8 0.778
#>  9     9 0.809
#> 10    10 0.789
#> # ℹ 35 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I can't use pre-made functions like simpson() because it's for an assignment.

Comment: You can implement your own simpson's D function and use it instead of `abdiv::simpson()` in the code example in my answer. I updated my answer to make use of a custom function.